# How to set a variable inside a PHP object

Tags: php, arrays, object, woocommerce

I want to update two variables in my the Woocommerce cart object. I can see the structure of the arrays in the object with:

```
echo 'Cart Dump: ' . var_dump($woocommerce->session->cart)
```

This returns:

```
array(1) { ["01822dd92bc31f60fdb64f0c3c5eb241"]=> array(9) { ["product_id"]=> int(616) ["variation_id"]=> string(0) "" ["variation"]=> string(0) "" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["addons"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Color" ["value"]=> string(13) "Black / Black" ["price"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(8) "Warranty" ["value"]=> string(13) "12 Month Free" ["price"]=> string(0) "" } } ["line_total"]=> float(689) ["line_tax"]=> float(0) ["line_subtotal"]=> float(689) ["line_subtotal_tax"]=> float(0) } } Cart Dump:
```

I want to be able to set the variables "value" and "price" inside that object.

My next step has been to try to step into the next array and have tried

```
echo 'Cart Dump: ' . var_dump($woocommerce->session->cart[1])
```

but I think I am mixing object references with array ones here and I am getting NULL. I can appreciate that I would be better off creating a function for the object but I am not sure how to best approach that if I cannot even access the variable I want to set.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no objects here, it's just that the array key is the string `01822dd92bc31f60fdb64f0c3c5eb241` and not the integer `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no objects here, it's just that the array key is the string `01822dd92bc31f60fdb64f0c3c5eb241` and not the integer `1`.

So to get / set your `value`, you would use:

```
$woocommerce->session->cart["01822dd92bc31f60fdb64f0c3c5eb241"]["addons"][0]["value"]
```

etc.

Depending on your php version you would probably need a temporary variable to get to the first element of your array if you don't know the key:

```
$temp = reset($woocommerce->session->cart);
$value = $temp["addons"][0]["value"];
```

Comment: Also, `cart[0]` would work and is probably easier I'd reckon. (First element in the `cart` array)

Comment: @Tikkes No, that would not work for an array array that does not have numeric keys. You could use `reset($woocommerce->session->cart)` to get the first element.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the prompt reply. The long hex key is generated by Woocommerce so I have to access it in a similar way as Tikkes suggests but it doesn't work. Using reset($woocom etc what do I put after ->cart?

Comment: Hi Jeroen that works great for getting the variable but I am still unsure of how I can set it. If I write $temp["addons"][0]["value"] = 'Foo bar'; it won't set the variable in the object but the $temp variable?

Comment: @Khrys Yes, if you want to set it in the object itself, you need the correct index or perhaps WooCommerce offers a setter method.

Comment: @Jeroen if I try to set it with $woocommerce->session->cart[0]['addons'][0]["value"] = "foo bar" I am still not able to set it but this seems to be correct. Is it the way I am referencing an array in an object?

Comment: Okay I am pretty much convinced that there is nothing wrong with the syntax but it is an issue with Woocommerce. We have chosen a different path.

Comment: @Khrys You are still using the wrong index if you use `cart[0]`. To get the actual key of the current array element, you can use `key($woocommerce->session->cart)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
//search the key of the array
$cart = $woocommerce->session->cart;
//update values using the key of the array as key
$woocommerce->session->cart[key($cart)]['value'] = 'your value';
$woocommerce->session->cart[key($cart)]['price'] = 'your price';
```

Comment: It would be nice if you'd try to clarify your answer a bit more.